# Beginner UML class diagram: am i allowed to do this kind of generalization

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I'm not sure how to describe this, so I came up with a rough diagram/scenario as an example:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/tuc8.png/

Say for example if a company has employees who are either part/full time, which are further branched into the types of employees(sales, admin...etc). How would I express this form of generalization? Is the way I express it in the diagram correct.

I tried looking for similar diagrams/scenarios in google, but couldn't find anything.
For now, lets say part time and full time classes have to be defined as a class/object(ie. the employment type cannot be specified as a string....)

Comment: Part time / full time seems only to be an attribute for the employee class. Full-time is just a particular value of part time. It's the upper limit of part time. So your declareHoursWorked could be INT.max in case of full-time for instance.

Comment: Thanks for answering . What if part time employees had a lot more unique methods as well, or what if I actually wanted to express this type of generalization as separate classes in other valid scenarios, would this be the right way to do it?

Comment: As Lyth said, part time and full time should be attributes to the employee itself as for example; a salesman can work on part time and full time basis, and so does the stripper!

Comment: Well, if you need to add more specification of employees... you would have a common class Employee. Then a class PartTimeEmployee that would extend Employee. And possibly the same for FullTimeEmployee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say something like that:

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, would never have thought of this :D

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using generalization sets. An instance can be of one subclass from every set.